# Extract values from html tags in a string?

Tags: c#, html

I have the following strings of HTML tags:

```
        string markup = "<b>this</b><s/><i>is</i><s/><r>text</r>";
        string markup2 = "<b>this</b><i>hello</i><i>is</i><r>text</r>";
        string markup3 = "<s/><b>this</b><i>hello</i><i>is</i><r>text</r>";
        string markup4 = "<b>this</b><i>hello</i><i>is</i><r>text</r><s/>";
        string markup5 = "<s/><b>this</b><i>hello</i><i>is</i><r>text</r><s/>";
        string markup6 = "<s/><b>this</b><i>hello</i><s/><s/><s/><r>text</r><i>is</i><s/>";
```

How can I extract the value inside each tag regardless of which string is used, and printing a space instead of the  s tag

Comment: Find  these substrings with a regex expression, then remove the tags from the result with another regex expression, then string replace </s> with " "

Comment: Load HTML into a HtmlDocument
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104/parsing-html-to-get-content-using-c-sharp

Comment: please don't ask questions about extract text of html. There are tons of answers about that on SO

Comment: @Glubus don't you dare to parse HTML with Regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/57508

Comment: He's not trying to parse html, he's trying to remove tags around text.

Comment: @Glubus *Find these substrings with a regex expression, then remove the tags from the result with another regex expression* ... You are explicitly suggesting Regex here ...

Comment: I agree with you that parsing HTML should not be done with Regex, though actually parsing HTML with regex means you have to take into account the semantics of HTML, i.e. do something else with <a> then with <p>. For OP's case, all he needs is to remove substrings in a specific format that happens to look like HTML, though the semantics of  the HTML do not matter at all.

Answer (score -1):

If the tags are "empty" (only "< s />") you basically replace a string in a string.
e.g.:

```
string x = markup.Replace("<s/>", " "); //Replaces all occurrences of <s/>
```

Comment: -, parsing HTML with Regex is simply wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/57508