# How to use string var to search website/ go to website

Tags: c#, youtube, video-streaming, searchbar

I am learning c# currently and I have questions about how to control website in c#, how c# can work with websites.

For example, let's say that I opened a chrome with a blank page.

```
Process.Start("http://blank.org/"); //<-  like this.
```

(Is there any way that I can open a blank page? - not very important tho..)

**Question 1)**

Now I would like to go to YouTube, using the address bar.
For example, I have :

```
string address = "www.youtube.com"
```

and I want to input this string in the address bar and automatically click search button.
Is it possible?

**Question 2)**

Let's say that I solved the question 1.
After that, I would like to search for something, using the search bar
For example, I have :

```
string keyword = "funny cat video";
```

Then I would like to input this keyword on the search bar and then search for it.

How can I make this?
Is it possible in c#?

**Question 3)**

And then I want to play the first result on the screen.
For example, like this :
[The first result that is found with the keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZWKO.jpg)

In this case, what should I do?

Thank you so much in advance. I have been googling all day and I couldn't find how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for a simple search:

```
string youtubeUrl = @"https://www.youtube.com";
string keyword = "funny cat video";

string searchUrl = string.Format("{0}/results?search_query={1}", youtubeUrl, keyword.Replace(" ", "+"));
Process.Start(searchUrl);
```

If you want to manipulate the search results, then you can use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword) to obtain the first result youtube VideoId.

If you don't want to use the [YouTube Search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search), then you will need to [download the html and parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038149/7988857) it to find the first video link on the page ( *like in jquery:* `$("a[href^='/watch?v=']")` ).

Once you have the youtube video id you want you can open and watch it.

```
string youtubeUrl = @"https://www.youtube.com";
string youtubeVideoId = "njSyHmcEdkw"; 

string watchVideoUrl = string.Format("{0}/watch?v={1}", youtubeUrl, youtubeVideoId);

Process.Start(watchVideoUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfect. Do you have also an idea about how to play the first result?

Comment: It helped me so much! Thank you so much again :D

Comment: I did. Thank you so much :D