# how to extract data for neural network from a website?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, neural-network

I have a neural network and I need to have an input data extracted from a couple of websites in some format (maybe xml?) so afterwards it will be used in my c# application, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if they supply RSS feeds. Otherwise check out how a crawler works. Also, HTML is basically XML.

There are similar questions asked already, for example:
[Parsing HTML to get content using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104/parsing-html-to-get-content-using-c-sharp)