# How would I extract certain information from a website into a table in c#

Tags: c#, collections

I have read in the information but I cant seem to figure out how to get the information I want ie the name, type etc into a table.
here what I did to get the data. ( I used a try-catch)

```
        string url = ("http://www.oiseaux-birds.com/card-laughing-dove.html");
        WebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            response = request.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
           
        }
       
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
            if (response != null)
                response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
           }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to coding can you please explain? the catch part was :  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }    

            I forgot to add it in the question sorry. if it makes any difference

Comment: If you can get the html then that is a start. Now think about how to get what you want from the response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104/parsing-html-to-get-content-using-c-sharp), how to parse html in c#.

Comment: You can edit your question to add catch part.